# iOS Swift get JSON data into tableView

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a JSON Data which I want to get into UITable. The data is dynamic so table should update every time view loads. Can anyone help?

```
{
data =     (
                {
            id = 102076330;
            name = "Vicky Arora";
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: are you sure it's the correct JSON format?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin This is the actual data. {
    data =     (
                {
            id = 1020763302139;
            name = "Vicky Arora";
        }
    );
    paging =     {
        next = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/XXXXXX";
    };
    summary =     {
        "total_count" = 13;
    };
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....

When you receive response,get the whole array of dictionary

```
if let arr = response["data"] as? [[String:String]] {
      YourArray = arr  
      // Define YourArray globally
}
```

Then in tableview cell,`cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
if let name = YourArray[indexpath.row]["name"] as? String{
      label.text = name
}
//Same You can done with id
```

And don't forget to set number of rows

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return YourArray.count
}
```

Comment: Use of unresolved identifier "responseObject"? Do you know what that is?

Comment: just show me how did you get response...and I''ll tell you what to do?

Comment: I am getting the YourArray correct. [[id: 102076330, name: Vicky Arora]] but when I use this in UITableView cellForRow, I get "fatal error: Array index out of range".      if let name = YourArray[indexPath.row]["name"] {
            cell.detailTextLabel!.text = name
        }. I tried if let name = YourArray[indexPath.row] - it is still crashing at this line with Array index out of range.

Comment: If you still get error....please post whole your viewcontroller code....easy for me to solve

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. But this sample i'm using Alamofire and SwitfyJSON. Import it using CocoaPod.

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class TableViewController: UITableViewController{

    var users: [JSON] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://xxxxx/users.json").responseJSON { (request, response, json, error) in
            if json != nil {
                var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                if let data = jsonObj["data"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                    self.users = data
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of sections.
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return users.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UserCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let user = users[indexPath.row]
        if let idLabel = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel {
            if let id = user["id"].string{
                idLabel.text = id
            }
        }

        if let nameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel {
            if let name = user["name"].string{
                nameLabel.text = name
            }
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are up to using Core Data, I would suggest using the `NSFetchedRequest`.

Every time you are getting the data from the server, save it to Core data, and that will automatically update the table view.

Here is a tutorial from [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)